# create new qoata : Warning storage level must be an integer that is greater than or equal to 0 and less than the

Tags: powershell, quota

I am using sp 2013. I try to create a new qoata template but still got this error:

> System.Management.Automation.SetValueInvocationException: Exception
>   setting "StorageWarningLevel": "Specified argument was out of the
>   range of valid values. Parameter name: **Warning storage level must be
>   an integer that is greater than or equal to 0 and less than the
>   maximum storage level.**" ---> System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException:
>   Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter
>   name: Warning storage level must be an integer that is greater than or
>   equal to 0 and less than the maximum storage level.    at
>   Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPQuota.set_StorageWarningLevel(Int64
>   value)    at CallSite.Target(Closure , CallSite , Object , Int64 )
>   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---    at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext
>   funcContext, Exception exception)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.Interpreter.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.LightLambda.RunVoid1[T0](T0
>   arg0)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipeImpl(Boolean
>   createLocalScope, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object
>   dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe,
>   InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.<>c__DisplayClass4.b__2()
>   at
>   System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceBase.RunActionIfNoRunningPipelinesWithThreadCheck(Action
>   action)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeWithPipe(Boolean
>   useLocalScope, ErrorHandlingBehavior errorHandlingBehavior, Object
>   dollarUnder, Object input, Object scriptThis, Pipe outputPipe,
>   InvocationInfo invocationInfo, Object[] args)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.ScriptBlock.InvokeUsingCmdlet(Cmdlet
>   contextCmdlet, Boolean useLocalScope, ErrorHandlingBehavior
>   errorHandlingBehavior, Object dollarUnder, Object input, Object
>   scriptThis, Object[] args)    at
>   Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ForEachObjectCommand.ProcessRecord()
>   at System.Management.Automation.CommandProcessor.ProcessRecord()

This is my powershell script:

```
Write-Host "Template not found, creating..." -NoNewline

        $quota = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPQuotaTemplate
        $quota.Name = $name
        $quota.StorageMaximumLevel = 20971520
        $quota.StorageWarningLevel = 5242880
        $quota.UserCodeWarningLevel = 100
        $quota.UserCodeMaximumLevel = 300

        $script:contentService.QuotaTemplates.Add($Quota)
        $script:contentService.Update()

        $result = 0
        Write-Host "Done" -ForegroundColor Green
```

what is going wrong?

Answer (score 1):

First, reference the web service, which is missing. Second, add the `UserCodeMaximumLevel` before you add the `UserCodeWarningLevel`. Third, add the new quota using the web service.

```
if ($ver.Version.Major -gt 1) {$host.Runspace.ThreadOptions = "ReuseThread"} 
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) 
{
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

$webService = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPWebService]::ContentService 

$quota=New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPQuotaTemplate
$quota.Name = "MyQuota"
$quota.StorageMaximumLevel = 20971520
$quota.StorageWarningLevel = 5242880
$quota.UserCodeMaximumLevel = 300
$quota.UserCodeWarningLevel = 100

$webService.QuotaTemplates.Add($quota)
```

Answer (score 0):

Was the quota template actually created? If yes, then the error can be ignored.

> It is possible that Sharepoint will throw an error:"Warning storage
>   level must be an integer that is greater than 0 and less than the
>   maximum storage level". As this error is thrown by SharePoint, not
>   SharePoint Provider, it can not be modified. The error message can be
>   safely ignored if  is set to be non-negative integer.

From [here](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd251791.aspx)